# virtualenv is not activated when I run "pip install -r requirements.txt"

Tags: python, virtualenv, pip

I am running a ubuntu 10.04 virtual machine on AWS ec2.

below is what happened to me:

```
source bin/activate
(env)$ pip install -r requirements.txt
(env)$ yolk -l  # no package was installed in my env
deactivate
$ yolk -l  # all packages were installed into /usr/lib and /usr/local

source bin/activate
(env)$ pip install simplejson==2.3.0
(env)$ yolk -l  # simplejson was installed in my env
```

a side question is how can I remove all packages not in my env.

Comment: @dm03514 pip freeze displays the same packages as yolk -l does.

Comment: Try `which python` to see which python is running. Maybe your `bin/activate` does not work properly.

Comment: @Rod "deactivate -> which python -> /usr/bin/python", "source bin/activate -> which python -> /directory/to/env/bin/python".

Comment: make sure `which pip` returns `/directory/to/env/bin/pip`

Comment: exactly same error here...

Comment: You might alwo try setting the environment variable `PIP_RESPECT_VIRTUALENV=true`.  I do this in my .bash_profile.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, activated virtualenv and pip install -r requirements.txt installed outside the env (in the site-packages for my base python installation).  It turned out that the ownership was causing the problem, the virtualenv I was trying to install to was owned by root instead of the currently active user.  In other words check the owner of the virtualenv youre installing to.

Answer (score -1):

try

```
workon env
pip install -r requirements
```

`env` should be your virtual environment's name

Comment: it looks like he was already working on the env `(env)` and he activated it